# How to interpret hex string as a character string in C

Tags: c, string, hex, string-concatenation

I have these strings of hex:
    `0F54C47A`
    `B97798C9`
    `348C211B`
    `0911F13F`
    `416E9759`

They are the result of five 
    `printf("%08X\n", sha_digest.Message_Digest[i]);` calls where i runs from 0 to 4.

I want to concatenate these strings to make one big string such as
`0F54C47AB97798C9348C211B0911F13F416E9759` and be able to reference that string with a `char *` variable.

Is there way to accomplish this in C? I know C++ has options but I my program is being made in C.

Many thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Just parse it char by char

Comment: [**What have you tried?**](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

In C, strings are arrays of characters, terminated by a null.    One way you could do it would be

```
char buf[8 * 5 + 1];
char *p = buf;
buf[0] = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
   sprintf(p, "%8x", sha_digest.Message_Digest[i]);
   p += 8;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much smoofra. I am very new to C so these things can be very tricky for me. Unfortunately, I still garbage values like `SZ??2?k?`. Interestingly, if I add the line `printf("%c%c%c%c\n", p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]);' right after the sprintf line I get a nice hex string, not only from the printf but from further use of the buffer. Does printf cause any casting?

Answer (score 0):

```
char buffer[41];

sprintf(buffer, "%08X%08X%08X%08X%08X", 
     sha_digest.Message_Digest[0],
     sha_digest.Message_Digest[1],
     sha_digest.Message_Digest[2],
     sha_digest.Message_Digest[3],
     sha_digest.Message_Digest[4]);
```

`buffer` is a C-style string contains `0F54C47AB97798C9348C211B0911F13F416E9759`.